# Como crear un trigger con sqlite3 en python

Tags: python, base-de-datos, sqlite3

Estoy haciendo una interfaz gráfica sencilla de una BBDD en la que se inserta un nombre, contraseña, apellido, dirección y comentario. Luego tienes cuatro botones que te permiten crear, leer, actualizar o eliminar esa información introducida de la base de datos. 
El problema que tengo es que he intentado hacer un trigger para que al actualizar información de un usario los antiguos datos se guarden en otra tabla diferente pero me salta un error y no sé como solucionarlo. 
Dejo aquí el codigo:

```
def update():

conexion=sqlite3.connect("Usuarios")
cursor=conexion.cursor()

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE USUARIO_ACTUALIZADO 
    (ANTERIOR_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ANTERIOR_NOMBRE 
    VARCHAR(50), ANTERIOR_PASSWORD VARCHAR(50), 
    ANTERIOR_APELLIDO VARCHAR(50), ANTERIOR_DIRECCION VARCHAR(50), 
    ANTERIOR_COMENTARIOS VARCHAR(50), USUARIO VARCHAR(50))
    ''')

cursor.execute('''CREATE TRIGGER USUARIO_ACTUALIZADO_BU BEFORE UPDATE ON 
    DATOSUSUARIOS FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO USUARIO_ACTUALIZADO (ANTERIOR_NOMBRE, ANTERIOR_PASSWORD, 
    ANTERIOR_APELLIDO, ANTERIOR_DIRECION, ANTERIOR_COMENTARIO, USUARIO, 
    FECHA) 
    VALUES (OLD.NOMBRE, OLD.PASSWORD, OLD.APELLIDO, OLD.DIRECCION, 
    OLD.COMENTARIOS, CURRENT_USER())
    ''')

datos= miNombre.get(), miPassword.get(), miApellido.get(), 
miDireccion.get(),comentariosCuadro.get("1.0", END)

cursor.execute("UPDATE DATOSUSUARIOS SET NOMBRE=?, PASSWORD=?, APELLIDO=?, 
DIRECCION=?, COMENTARIOS=? WHERE ID= " + miId.get(), (datos))

conexion.commit()
messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "Registro actualizado con éxito")
```

Por cierto estoy usando sqlite3

Comment: por curiosidad, porque quieres hacer un trigger a algo que solo se va a actualizar una sola vez

Comment: Me uno a la duda de JackNavaRow, no obstante si dices "pero me salta un error y no sé como solucionarlo" ¿Podrías mostrar el error por favor?

Comment: @JackNavaRow porque cada vez que se actualice algún dato de la BBDD quiero que se guarde el anterior a modo de backup, además también quiero hacerlo para cuando se elimine un usuario.

Comment: @FJSevilla el error que me da es este:

Comment: @FJSevilla Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PROGRAMAS\PHYTON\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "G:\PROGRAMACION\PHYTON\PRACTICA GUIADA\Programa_Practica.py", line 96, in update
    ''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "INSERT": syntax error
[Finished in 17.6s]

Comment: para eso respaldas el archivo sqllite y no tienes que hacer eso

Answer (score 0):

No sé si lo hayas resulto pero dejo el comentario por si alguien tiene el mismo problema con `Triggers` en `SQLite`.

Te faltó poner el `BEGIN` y el `END`.

Tendrías que haber hecho así para solucionar el error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "INSERT": syntax error`

```
cursor.execute('''CREATE TRIGGER USUARIO_ACTUALIZADO_BU BEFORE UPDATE ON 
    DATOSUSUARIOS FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO USUARIO_ACTUALIZADO (ANTERIOR_NOMBRE, ANTERIOR_PASSWORD, 
    ANTERIOR_APELLIDO, ANTERIOR_DIRECION, ANTERIOR_COMENTARIO, USUARIO, 
    FECHA) 
    VALUES (OLD.NOMBRE, OLD.PASSWORD, OLD.APELLIDO, OLD.DIRECCION, 
    OLD.COMENTARIOS, CURRENT_USER()); 
    END;
    ''')
```